# Отладка PHP в Visual Studio Code - не выводятся сообщения журнала в консоль отладки

Tags: php, консоль, visual-studio-code, отладка

В целом отладка работает. Добавил сообщение в точку ведения журнала, но в консоль не выводится это сообщение (точка останова срабатывает). В чем может быть причина? Отладчик стандартный - PHP Debug.

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, что не поддерживается этот тип точек останова: "Breakpoints of this type are not supported by the debugger".